# Create new webdriver session manually

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-requests

I am trying to play a little bit with `WebDriver Protocol` using `Python` and `requests` module.

I started `chromedriver` binary:

```
$ chromedriver_2.31 
Starting ChromeDriver 2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
```

So far so good.

But the problem is that I get `session not created` exception when trying to create a session:

```
import requests

r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:9515/session", {})

print("Status: " + str(r.status_code))
print("Body: " + str(r.content))
```

Execution output:

```
Status: 200
Body: b'{"sessionId":"286421fcd381ee0471418ebce7f3e125","status":33,"value":{"message":"session not created exception: Missing or invalid capabilities\\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Linux 4.4.0-91-generic x86_64)"}}'
```

I searched through the [WebDriver Protocol docs](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#new-session), but I couldn't find information about which capabilities are mandatory or something like that.

So, I tried with some random capabilities:

```
import requests

data = {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "version": "",
        "platform": "LINUX",
        "javascriptEnabled": "true",
        "acceptInsecureCerts": "false",
        "cssSelectorsEnabled": "true"
        }

r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:9515/session", data)

print("Status: " + str(r.status_code))
print("Body: " + str(r.content))
```

But again fail:

```
Status: 400
Body: b'missing command parameters'
```

Do you have any ideas what is the problem and how to fix it?

*UPDATE*

Also tried:

```
import requests


data = """
        {
            desiredCapabilities: {  
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "version": "",
            "platform": "ANY"
            }
        }
    """

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:9515/session", json=data, headers=headers)

print("Status: " + str(r.status_code))
print("Body: " + str(r.content))
```

Again error:

```
Status: 400
Body: b'missing command parameters'
```

Comment: That's a nice question.. I'm tinkering with it. Check this out: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

Comment: @JugurthaHadjar the link you mentioned is about specific language binding to the WebDriver Protocol. I am trying to use it as raw http requests

Comment: It's not important. I'm also using the requests library (by the way, the driver expects a json object so I think you'd use:

`r = requests.post('http://localhost:9515/session', json=data)`

The driver has a specific API, so whether you find resources in Javascript or Python, they have to respect it.

Comment: I searched for the exception message and I found this: https://github.com/bayandin/chromedriver/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Missing+or+invalid+capabilities&type=

As you notice, the word is `desiredCapabilities`. I look at Selenium and I find this: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities

Comment: @JugurthaHadjar please take a look at the update. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, but you should get a 200 telling you it couldn't create a session. Like the one you had before:

`b'{"sessionId":"ac4f0aed221bc6d7a3227a0cd2a1a774","status":33,"value":{"message":"session not created exception: Missing or invalid capabilities\\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477729 (e5aa99d9d101379b1542958a71df3f50913f1ea2),platform=Linux 4.4.0-91-generic x86)"}}'`

`r = requests.post('http://localhost:9515/session', json=data)`. Gives me a 200.

Comment: Well, it keeps failing creating a session :( What can I do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151923/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-jugurtha-hadjar).

Comment: I'm looking at selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py, WebDriver class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I looked at how Selenium does it..:

`selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py`, class `RemoteConnection`, method `execute`. I raised an exception for params, like this:

```
raise Exception(params)
```

Here's what came out:

```
{'capabilities': {'alwaysMatch': {'browserName': 'chrome',
   'chromeOptions': {'args': [], 'extensions': []},
   'platform': 'ANY',
   'version': ''},
  'firstMatch': []},
 'desiredCapabilities': {'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {'args': [], 'extensions': []},
  'platform': 'ANY',
  'version': ''}}
```

So, doing the same thing, with `data` our new found dictionary:

```
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:9515/session', json=data)
# A new chromium window is created
r.content
`b'{"sessionId":"94cf6af9577d323eb51f6340b1fd2d07","status":0,"value":{"acceptSslCerts":true,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"browserName":"chrome","chrome":{"chromedriverVersion":"2.30.477729 (e5aa99d9d101379b1542958a71df3f50913f1ea2)","userDataDir":"/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.uqwViV"},"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"handlesAlerts":true,"hasTouchScreen":false,"javascriptEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":true,"mobileEmulationEnabled":false,"nativeEvents":true,"networkConnectionEnabled":false,"pageLoadStrategy":"normal","platform":"Linux","rotatable":false,"takesHeapSnapshot":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"unexpectedAlertBehaviour":"","version":"60.0.3112.78","webStorageEnabled":true}}'`
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to post json data containing capabilities and desired capabilities. `alwaysMatch` can contain any or more of the following:

- acceptInsecureCerts
- browserName
- browserVersion
- platformName
- pageLoadStrategy
- proxy
- setWindowRect
- timeouts
- unhandledPromptBehavior

```
    params = {
        'capabilities': {
            'firstMatch': [{}], 
            'alwaysMatch': {
                ...
            }
        },
        'desiredCapabilities': {
            'browserName': 'chrome',
            'version': '60',
            'platform': 'MAC'
        }
    }
```

r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:9515/session', json=params)

### Reference:

- [Selenium Command](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py#L229)
- [Desired Capabilities](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities)

Answer (score 1):

chromedriver (as of 2.41 at least) simply does not support the WebDriver protocol.

The missing capability required by chromedriver is `capabilities.alwaysMatch.goog:chromeOptions.w3c: true`

**Update**: chromedriver 76 has much better webdriver support (to the point where normal webdriver clients usually start working) but still doesn't implement the protocol fully.